# NSDate increment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk

i'm trying to increment nsdate by 1 month, however when it reaches the end of the year, the year does not update (starts again from the first month)? How could this be fixed?

this is what code i used

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *comp = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[comp setMonth: 1];
NSDate* newDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comp toDate:oldDate options:NSWrapCalendarComponents];
```

Answer (score 5):

That's what the `NSWrapCalendarComponents` option does. Pass `0` instead to get the behavior you're looking for.